# Character counting program infinite loop

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

I seem to be falling into an infinite loop on a character counting program I'm working on for class. Please take a look and let me know where I need improvement. I've been working on this thing for quite awhile and keep running into the same situation.  Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int WordLength();
void DisplayCount(int wordCount[]);

int main()
{
    int L;
    int Num_of_Char[16]={0};

    cout<<"Please enter some text:\n";

    L=WordLength();

    while (L)
    {
        L=WordLength();
        Num_of_Char[L]+=1;
    }

    DisplayCount(Num_of_Char);

}

/***************************************WordLength*******************************************
*   Action:         Analyzes the text that has been entered and decides what is and isn't   *
*                   a word (mainly by separating words by whitespaces and not accepting     *
*                   most punctuation as part of a word with the exception of hyphens which  *
*                   carry a partial word to the next line as well as apostrophes.           *
*                                                                                           *
*   Parameters:                                                                             *
*       IN:                                                                                 *
*                                                                                           *
*       OUT:                                                                                *
*                                                                                           *
*                                                                                           *
*   Returns:        The length of each word.                                                *
*                                                                                           *
*   Precondition:                                                                           *
*********************************************************************************************/
int WordLength()
{
    char ch;
    int End_Of_Word=0, Length=0; 

    ch=cin.get();

    while((!cin.eof())||(!End_Of_Word))
    {
        while (!isspace(ch))    //Spaces are delimeters of words
        {

            if(isalnum(ch))     //if current character is a alpha numeric character it is counted as part of the word
            {
                ++Length;
                cin.get(ch);
            }

            if ((ch=='\'')&&(isalnum(cin.peek())))  //apostrophes are counted as part of the word
            {
                ++Length;
            }

            if ((ch=='-')&&(isalnum(cin.peek()=='\n'))) //the hyphen as part of the word if followed by newline
            {
                ++Length;
            }
            if((isspace(ch))||(ispunct(ch))||(ch=='\n'))
            {
                ++End_Of_Word;

            }
        }
    }
    return Length;
}


/***************************************DisplayCount*****************************************
*   Action:         Displays how many words have a specific character count between 1 and   *
*                   15 characters. Then displays the average word character size.           *
*                                                                                           *
*   Parameters:                                                                             *
*       IN:         wordArray, which points to the array that holds the count of each word's*
*                   character size.                                                         *
*                                                                                           *
*       OUT:        Displays the array contents in a grid style as well as an average       *
*                   word size based on the contents of the array.                           *
*                                                                                           *
*   Returns:                                                                                *
*                                                                                           *
*   Precondition:   wordArray points to an int array                                        *
*********************************************************************************************/
void DisplayCount(int wordArray[])
{
    double sum = 0;
    cout<<"\tWord Length\t\t"<<"Frequency\n";
    cout<<"\t-----------\t\t"<<"---------\n";

    for(int i=1; i<16; i++) 
    {
        cout<<"\t     "<<i<<"\t\t\t    "<<wordArray[i]<<endl;   //Displays the contents of each element
        sum+=(i*wordArray[i]);  //Keeps a running total of contents of array
    }

    cout<<"\tAverage word length:  "<<sum/(15)<<endl;       //Displays the average word length
}
```

Comment: `!End_Of_Word` (i.e. `!0`, i.e. 1) might be your loop problem. There are other problems.

Answer (score 1):

Doing input of character only in certain conditions ensures that it's not done in other cases.

For example, in the code

```
    while (!isspace(ch))    //Spaces are delimeters of words
    {

        if(isalnum(ch))     //if current character is a alpha numeric character it is counted as part of the word
        {
            ++Length;
            cin.get(ch);
        }
```

if `ch` is not a space then the outer loop will keep on iterating, and if it so happens that `ch` is not alphanumeric then the `cin.get` will not be executed, then going on to the next iteration of the outer loop, and so on.

A good way to realize what's going on in such cases, is to run the program in a **source code level debugger**. Visual Studio in Windows has one that's pretty good. Then just single-step your way through the program execution, noting well for each step what's going on.

---

One unrelated but important matter: the C character classification functions such as `isalnum` do not accept negative arguments other than `EOF`. Thus for international use a simple call with a `char` value will generally have Undefined Behavior, and might crash the program in a debug build. So, always cast a `char` actual argument to `unsigned char`.

---

Another unrelated but important matter: `void main` is non-standard, will cause your program to be rejected by many compilers (including g++), and is one character more to type than just `int main`. In other words it's pretty silly to write `void main`. AFAIK the only professionals doing that are some (or perhaps most) Microsoft employees, for unknown reasons  –  but it means that you can encounter `void main` e.g. in code generated by Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm a little brain dead at the moment, I've been at this so long and tomorrow is my due date. Could you give me a code example of how to correct the issue? Should I place a cin.get(ch) above the first if statement?